# A question about Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Let $F:=\{F_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ be the Fibonacci sequence (defined by 
$ F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ with $F_1=F_2=1$).

- Is it true that there exists an **infinite** set of **integers** $B$ such that
  $(F-F)\cap (B-B)=\{ 0\}$?

(note that $A-A=\{a_1-a_2: a_1,a_2\in A\}$)

Comment: [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base) might help (not sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: Given a set $T$ of integers in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, we can find a subset $B$ of size at least $n/2|T|$ such that $(B-B) \cap T$ is empty.

Now let $T=(F-F) \cap \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Note that $|T|=O(\log^2n)$ because the $n$th Fibonacci number is approximately $1.61^n$. Thus you can find a $B$ such that $(B-B) \cap (F-F)$ is $\{0\}$ and in fact has at least $\Omega(\dfrac{n}{\log ^2n})$ elements in the first $n$ natural numbers.

Proof of Claim:
Initialize $B=\{1\}$. 
While $|B|<n/2|T|$, add $b$ to $B$ such that $(b-B) \cup (B-b)$ avoids $T$ except for zero.
This is possible if $H=(B-T) \cup (T-B)$ does not exhaust $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
Since $|H| \leq 2|B||T|$, it is possible if $|B| <\dfrac{n}{2|T|}$.

Comment: @-Aravind.  What did you mean by $\Omega(\dfrac{n}{\log ^2n})$?

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation for the Big-Omega notation. In the calculation done here, you could just think of it as $\dfrac{n}{4\log^2 n}$.

Comment: Thanks, So  the $O$ and $\Omega$ notations in your answer are the same.